# QML How to call method of a model from the delegate

Tags: qt, qml

I have a simple QML program which has one `ListView`. ListView's model and delegate are defined in a separate QML files.

```qml
//Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
//import TheModel.qml
//import TheDelegate.qml


Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: theModel
        delegate: theDelegate
        focus: true

    }
    Button{
        x: 394
        y: 257
        text: "press me"
       onPressed: theModel.append({"color":"black", "cost": 5.95, "name":"Pizza"})
   }

    TheDelegate{
        id: theDelegate
    }

    TheModel{
        id:theModel
    }
}
```

then the model file

```qml
//TheModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel{
    ListElement {
        color:"red";
        name: "Bill Smith"
        number: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement {
        color:"blue";
        name: "John Brown"
        number: "555 8426"
    }
    ListElement {
        color:"green";
        name: "Sam Wise"
        number: "555 0473"
    }
}
```

and finally the delegate

```qml
    //TheDelegate.qml
    import QtQuick 2.0
    
    Component {
        Rectangle{
            color: model.color
            width: 100
            height: 100
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed: model.append({"color":"black", "cost": 5.95, "name":"Pizza"})
            }
        }
    }
```

if I click on delegate's `MouseArea` the `onPressed` method will need to create one `ListItem`, but the issue is that I cannot access the model's function from delegate. what is confusing though, that properties are being accessed in delegate through `model`.
can anyone point out on the right way of doing this, say if I know that the model is a `ListModel` and it has `append` method, but delegate doesn't know that, is there a way to cast model to known type then call a method of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by adding a signal to `TheDelegate`, which you can connect in the scope where `theModel` is available. I'd like to call this 'contained components', there is probably some fancy term for it ;-)

Please change `TheDelegate.qml` to (btw, I also changed it to not be a `Component`, for reusability):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle{
    color: model.color
    width: 100
    height: 100

    signal appendRequested(var newItem)

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: appendRequested({"color":"black", "cost": 5.95, "name":"Pizza"})
    }
}
```

Then in `main.qml` you can use it as following:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: theModel
    delegate: theDelegate

    focus: true
}

Component {
    id: theDelegate

    TheDelegate {
        onAppendRequested: theModel.append(newItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it , it's like a late binding. because delegate is valid to be used on it's own but when used in view , the view only knows who is the model. but one question is popping out here. why the line "color: model.color" is working?

Answer (score 3):

The model object is exposed to each delegate in a view, and it provides the model data for that particular delegate. It is not the same as the ListView's model property.

@Amfasis' approach is nice, because it will work with any type of model and view.

If you don't mind tying the delegate to ListView, you can use the attached ListView API:

```
Component {
    Rectangle{
        id: root
        color: model.color
        width: 100
        height: 100
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: root.ListView.view.model.append({"color":"black", "cost": 5.95, "name":"Pizza"})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you assuming that above Component is in the same qml file as the ListView? because is I will change onPressed : root.....    then the root is Component itself. also if so then I don't have issue knowing the model as it can be accessed from ListView's id property.

Comment: This answer was given assuming that the Component would stay in its own file.